# Convert an Sql request into json but with a specific format

Tags: javascript, php, sql, angularjs, json

My problem : I can have a Json format but not the format I want. I show you my code then and then I show you my Json model I want. I don't know how to proceed, if I must change my php code, my js code or my database, I think that is the array of fetchAll() that isn't properly adapted to me. I really need help for this... The code is working it's just not the good format. I'm using AngularJs, Html, Css, and php only for sql request and database. I tell you about what i'm using because it may exist a solution in Js or in php or even my sql request which can be inappropriate...

My php code:

```
$request = $bdd->prepare('
    SELECT z.name zoneName, c.name columnName, w.name woodName 
    FROM zones z
    JOIN columns c ON (c.ID_zone = z.ID)
    JOIN woods w ON (w.ID_column = c.ID)
    ');

$request->execute();
$result = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

My result in Json :

```
        [{"zoneName":"A1","columnName":"C1","woodName":"10-27-050-03\/17"},
        {"zoneName":"A1","columnName":"C1","woodName":"42-27-050-03\/17"},
        {"zoneName":"A1","columnName":"C2","woodName":"20-23-050-03\/17"},
        {"zoneName":"A2","columnName":"C3","woodName":"90-37-050-03\/17"}]
```

The result I want:

```
{"zoneName":[{"columnName": [[{"id":"woodName"},{"id":"woodName"},...]]},{"columnName": [[{"id":"woodName"},{"id":"woodName"}, ...]]},...],"zoneName":[{"columnName": [[{"id":"woodName"},{"id":"woodName"}, ...]]},{"columnName": [[{"id":"woodName"},{"id":"woodName"}, ...]]},...],...}
```

Comment: `["id":"woodName","id":"woodName", ...]` not possible. Array/object doesn't contain duplicate key

Comment: you will never get a json response in that way . what you don't like in the result you get ?

Comment: Of course I made a mistake, thanks B. Desai, I edited it.

Comment: I don't like the result I get because I'm creating an application with one block of zoneName which contains all of its columnName which contains all of its woodName, so with this json I can't nest it as I want

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeed, but not in the way I wanted... Then I don't want to make this subject solved because I made my own Json from my request directly. The way I still want a solution is with an sql request which will return me directly the Json I want with the php functions fetchAll() + json_encode().

The code I did (it works) :

```
$result = $conn->query("
    SELECT z.nom nomZone, c.nom nomColonne, p.nom nomPalette 
    FROM zones z
    JOIN colonnes c ON (c.ID_zone = z.ID)
    JOIN palettes p ON (p.ID_colonne = c.ID)
    ORDER BY nomZone, nomColonne, nomPalette
    ");

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($rs["nomColonne"] != $colonnePrecedente && $rs["nomZone"] == $zonePrecedente && $colonnePrecedente != NULL)
    {
        $outp .= ']]},';
    }
    elseif ($rs["nomColonne"] != $colonnePrecedente && $colonnePrecedente != NULL)
    {
        $outp .= ']]}';
    }
    if ($rs["nomZone"] != $zonePrecedente && $zonePrecedente != NULL)
    {
        $outp .= "],";
    }
    if ($rs["nomZone"] != $zonePrecedente)
    {    
        $outp .= '"'                           . $rs["nomZone"]           . '":[';
    }
    if ($rs["nomColonne"] != $colonnePrecedente)
    {
        $outp .= "".'{"type":"container","id":"'  . $rs["nomColonne"]        . '","columns":[[';
    }
    $outp .= "".'{"type":"item","id":"'     . $rs["nomPalette"]        . '"}';
    if ($rs["nomColonne"] != $colonnePrecedente)
    {
        $outp .= ",";
    }


    $zonePrecedente = $rs["nomZone"];
    $colonnePrecedente = $rs["nomColonne"];
    $palettePrecedente = $rs["nomPalette"];
}
$outp ='{'.$outp.']]}]}';
$conn->close();
```

I know that my code isn't clean but I don't have enough experience in programming.

The result of $outp :

```
{"A1":[{"type":"container","id":"C1","columns":[[{"type":"item","id":"10-27-050-03_17"},{"type":"item","id":"10-28-050-03_17"}]]},{"type":"container","id":"C2","columns":[[{"type":"item","id":"20-23-050-03_17"},{"type":"item","id":"20-23-050-03_18"}]]}],"A2":[{"type":"container","id":"C1","columns":[[{"type":"item","id":"30-27-052-03_17"},{"type":"item","id":"30-27-052-03_17"}]]},{"type":"container","id":"C2","columns":[[{"type":"item","id":"40-27-050-03_17"},{"type":"item","id":"40-28-050-03_17"}]]},{"type":"container","id":"C3","columns":[[{"type":"item","id":"50-27-050-03_17"},{"type":"item","id":"50-28-050-03_17"}]]}],"A3":[{"type":"container","id":"C1","columns":[[{"type":"item","id":"60-27-050-03_17"},{"type":"item","id":"60-27-050-03_17"}]]},{"type":"container","id":"C2","columns":[[{"type":"item","id":"70-27-050-03_17"},{"type":"item","id":"70-27-050-03_17"}]]}],"A4":[{"type":"container","id":"C1","columns":[[{"type":"item","id":"80-27-050-03_17"},{"type":"item","id":"80-28-050-03_17"}]]},{"type":"container","id":"C2","columns":[[{"type":"item","id":"90-27-040-03_17"},{"type":"item","id":"90-27-050-03_17"}]]}]}
```

Even if I got the output I wanted, I'm still looking for solution because now it will be very hard for me to manipulate my database.

Have a nice day

Comment: Still waiting for a solution, someone?